# On paste StartFragment - EndFragment Postman issue

Tags: postman, copy, copy-paste

Whenever I copy content into the Postman editor, it adds 'StartFragment' and 'EndFragment' tags around the pasted content, How can I prevent Postman from adding these tags automatically, or is there a way to configure Postman to exclude them? I find myself removing them manually every time, which is really frustrating.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that we can use `ctrl+shift+V` to prevent the default behavior of any editor on pasting.